# How to use Jupyter Lab or similar IDE without starting a new sessione everytime

Tags: unix, anaconda, jupyter, rstudio-server

I am using a Unix Server machine and want my mates to be able to use it for data science purposes.
I have installed Anconda and RStudio.

They can easily connect and use RStudio Server via web-browser (on their desktop) using a no-login user on the machine (server), so no need to ssh connection to the machine for the enduser.

How can i achieve the same for anaconda or jupyter?

Now i'm trying Jupyter-Lab but everytime a user needs to use it it has to connect via ssh to the server write

```
jupyter -lab
```

to start the server, copy the url with the auth token and paste it in the client-side browser.

I want to be able to make end-user able to connect to anaconda or jupyter without getting access to the server machine like in the case of Rstudio Server.

Any help? I'm not very fond on these topics.

Comment: Have a look at https://jupyter.org/hub

Comment: please explain a little more ...

Comment: You can run Jupyter Hub on your server, just like you run RStudio Server now. Your users can than interact with Jupyter notebooks without having to start Jupyter Lab. But that is really off-topic for SO ...